# How to convert a .net framework (not core) project from obsolete project.json format

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, project.json

I have an existing set of .net Framework projects (.csproj webapi)  that need to be converted to the modern non project.json formats. However I seem to be running into a google black hole and cannot find the definitive instructions on what I need to do to my csproj files to convert them from the old project.json dependent format.

I found number places that talk about a `dotnet migrate` tool, but that seems to be obsolete now and certainly doesn't seem to be found, when running the dotnet cli.

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-migrate does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Can anyone point me at steps needed please?

Comment: I wonder if you use Net Core 3.0 sdk. And as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-migrate) said, `dotnet migurate` is abandoned in Net core 3.x. And you can only use it in Net Core 2.x sdk. And you can follow [this guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/#dotnet-migrate).

Comment: Thanks @PerryQian-MSFT